# Are state boundaries a problem when using taxis in the USA?

Tags: usa, taxis

I've heard that in the United States, taxi licenses may be local, so that taxis might not be allowed to cross from one state to another.  However, I've also seen reports of people taking very long distance taxi rides.

Do I need to care about state boundaries if planning a long distance taxi ride in the United States, for example, [from Dyer (Nevada) to Benton (California)](http://goo.gl/maps/b3pR3) (provided I can phone them for a pick-up)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Taxis cross state borders all the time. Probably half of Hoboken, New Jersey takes the taxi home from New York City on any given weekend night, and New York has some of the most restrictive taxi laws in the country.

Taxi licensing is mostly local, at the city or county level. A cab driver is only permitted to *pick up* passengers from a jurisdiction where they are licensed to do so. So, if you are in Dyer, you can almost certainly get a Dyer taxi to take you to Benton, but you may or may not be allowed to have a Benton taxi come pick you up in Dyer.

If you cross a city or county line (much less a state line), expect to cover the cost for the driver's return to his own jurisdiction in some way. A New York City taxi will charge a surcharge just for leaving New York City— and a metered rate is not possible at all for going to New Jersey; you must negotiate a flat fare with the driver (as well as pay tolls for the round trip). Washington, D.C. cabs charge a special rate for mileage beyond the District of Columbia. Since this is a rural area, you may even be required to pay the full fare of a return trip.

The taxi company will inform you of any special requirements for crossing county or state lines when you call to arrange your ride.

Comment: *Probably half of Hoboken, New Jersey takes the taxi home from New York City on any given weekend night* - that's an exaggeration.  "Limo" yes.  Not the taxi/cab.

Comment: Ah well, unfortunately Dyer is a tiny village with surely no taxi services, and my hope was to call a taxi in the nearest town (which is in California) for pickup in Nevada.

Comment: @gerrit I would still call and see if something can be arranged— the taxi company might offer a private car service, for example, which would not be subject to the same regulations. This is how I can arrange for a Maryland-based taxi driver to pick me up at Dulles Airport which is not only in Virginia, but has granted a monopoly on pickup rights to another company— because my driver is picking me up as prearranged private car.

Comment: @Karlson Perhaps among your friends, but the half of Hoboken I hang out with often in neither, scuttling back at 4am on the PATH train. :)

Comment: @choster I used to be that "half" and I used to call a car rather then trying to hail a cab @ 3-4 am even on the weekend.  And it wasn't half or even a third...

Comment: NYC is probably the biggest example but there are plenty of other decent-sized urban areas that straddle state lines. Some that spring immediately to my mind are Chicago's metro area spilling into Indiana; (East) St Louis (Missouri/Illinois); Kansas City (Missouri/Kansas); Omaha/Council Bluffs (Nebraska/Iowa); Toledo, Ohio, extending into Michigan. Actually, now I'm wondering what happens with the US/Canadian border (Detroit and Windsor, Buffalo and Niagara Falls, Port Huron and Sarnia).

Answer (score 7):

In this particular case there doesn't seem to be an issue [as per laws of state of Nevada](http://www.leg.state.nv.us/NRS/NRS-706.html) but it is generally not permitted for a cab companies from out of the licensing jurisdiction in this case state of California to pick up passengers there.

So because of this taxis usually charge passengers taking such trips for both forward and return.

Answer (score 5):

In the United States it would make more sense to hire a car or limo service for a long haul as opposed to a taxi. In the US, a rule of thumb would be to use taxis around town and car services for trips further than 30 miles. 
Concerning crossing state lines, a taxi can cross a state line to drop you off, but not to pick you up. Of course since Dyer is a such a small town, the nearest out of state taxi service might be willing to pick you up without fear of getting caught by local code enforcement.